# Find total amount of selected graph values from Kendo chart

Tags: javascript, object, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I'm trying to implement a kendo chart similar to this
[Chart API / Selection](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/chart-api/selection)
In the example provided with link, it has a selection handle that can be used to select a range, and it can console log the starting and end points of selection. However i'm trying to console log the total sum of value in a selected range. For instance, in the given example of Total Olympic medals won by USA, I want to find total number of gold, silver and bronze medals in a selected period. Also it has to console log real-time values when user scrolls mouse-wheel to change selection. How to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the referenced example you can loop through the series of the chart and then for each series you can loop through the data over the selected range and add up the totals:

```
function formatRange(e) {
  var categories = e.axis.categories;
  var msg =  kendo.format("({0}-{1}) ",
           categories[e.from],categories[e.to - 1]);

  for (var i=0; i<e.sender.options.series.length; i++){
    var name = e.sender.options.series[i].name;
    console.log(name);
    var total = 0;
    for (var j=e.from; j<e.to; j++){
      total += e.sender.options.series[i].data[j];
    }
    msg = msg + kendo.format(" {0}: {1};",
           name,total);
  }                 
  return msg;
}
```

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/YGZKxa)**